# Reflect html changes in browser without restarting the express app

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express app. I am using swig as the template engine. 
Is it possible to reflect my HTML changes in the browser when I click refresh. I don't want to restart the server every time I need to do a HTML change?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the solution from this [link](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-restart-on-file-change.html).

I installed supervisor module as global installation

```
npm install supervisor -g
```

I stated my app like this

```
supervisor -e html,js  app.js
```

Here i am specifying to watch the changes in files with extensions .html and .js.
So when these files are changed its automatically reloaded when the next request comes.No restart required.

Comment: Where u wrote 'supervisor -e html,js  app.js'?
Please suggest. mine not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of tools for this:

- [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)
- [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor)
- [node-hot-reload](https://github.com/shimondoodkin/node-hot-reload)

And I'm sure you could find more.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply disable swig's caching:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });
}
```