# How to run project in Google Cloud using Node js

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform

How to run new project in Google Cloud Platform using Node js without run commands  again and again for run file in Google Cloud Shell

Comment: what do you want to do? Can you please explain briefly?

Comment: @deepbchudasama Sorry i'm wasting your time but i get the solution for my problem .But i have get the new problem  Cloud Sql query is not working after deploy project .

Comment: No you aren't wasting my time :) Feel free to share your problem regarding SQL Query.

Comment: I have seen your recent questions you seems like new in Web Development!

Comment: @deepbchudasama thank you so much and i'm not new in Web Development but i'm learning a new programming languages. So i have facing some issues.

Comment: @deepbchudasama i have run gcloud app deploy command in Google Colud Shell but i think this is not connect Cloud MySQL . How can i check this is connect or not to Cloud MySQL. I have some changes in code and run this command  my html is working properly but where i'm using query is not working

Comment: @deepbchudasama why these command run again and again in shell. I have seem like this error 
Error connecting: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/home/shivanichourasiya82/nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:411:13)

if these command is not run again and again

Comment: @deepbchudasama how i am connect node js to Cloud MySQL permanently.So i can not get the error again

Comment: Probably you have problem with your connection and with **node.js** you have to work with asynchronous operations so, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40868716/8348558

Answer (score 0):

You can install a supervisor module as explained in the [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13967472/10553701).

To install the supervisor module run below command:

> **npm install supervisor -g**

And then run you application with the command:

> **supervisor -e html,js  app.js**

This will monitor all .html and .js files for any changes and update the content of your web pages without a restart of application. Of course,  You will need to reload the web page.

Comment: I'm run deploy command in Google Cloud Shell and run the project url in the browser https://[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com. But i have get error 502 in node js api response

Comment: This 502 error can be caused by a number of reasons. You will have to check your logs for detailed message. Check your logs in Stackdriver and see the StackOverflow answer that explains how to get nginx logs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021633/10553701)